# @PostInitialize part of which package

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I wish to use the @PostInitialize annotation in one of my bean to load few properties after initialization is completed. Can someone please let me know where can I find this annotation? What maven dependency I need to add to get this annotation? Why is this not part of Spring 3.2.4 or am I missing some package of spring which I should have added?

Please advise

**UPDATE**

I tried using resthubs @PostInitialize but it does not work. Do I have to do any other configuration to get this annotation to work.

Comment: Do you mean RESTHub's @PostInitialize? http://resthub.org/javadoc/2.0/org/resthub/common/util/PostInitialize.html

Comment: Do I really need to use resthubs @Postinitialize. So just for one annotation I will have to have entire dependency which I will not be using anyways.

Comment: If you read the link above you can see that PostInitialize is like Spring's @PostConstruct annotation: "Similar to PostConstruct Spring annotation, but executed later in application lifecycle, in order to get transaction management ready."

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean `@PostConstruct`.

From the 3.2.4 [reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-nature)  manual,

> The JSR-250 @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy annotations are generally considered best practice for receiving lifecycle callbacks in a modern Spring application. Using these annotations means that your beans are not coupled to Spring specific interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

What you request is the patch from the Spring improvement request https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-5966.

Answer (score 0):

RestHub has an @PostInitialize annotation. Checkout [Resthub @GitHub](https://github.com/resthub/) or [Resthub API](http://resthub.github.io/apidocs/spring/2.0/org/resthub/common/util/PostInitialize.html).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.resthub</groupId>
    <artifactId>resthub-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

**@PostInitialize** and **@PostConstruct** are different.

In most cases you will be OK with **@PostConstruct**.

BUT!

The **@PostContruct** it's not called via spring proxies so for example the **@Transactional** won't work with **@PostConstruct**.

Because of these situations **@PostInitialize** is invented, which is called after context refreshed and it will be called via proxy so **@Transactional** will work with it.

Spring doesn't have **@PostInitialize** by default (because of lazy init beans) but you can add this dependency and you will have it:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>fr.zebasto</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-postinitialize</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Find more info here: https://github.com/bcecchinato/spring-postinitialize